# How to delete nodes without in-edge and out-edge

Tags: nebula-graph

NebulaGraph version: v3.1.0

How can I delete those nodes which have no links with other nodes?

delete isolated nodes, which has no in-edge and out-edge.

Comment: Related: *[Is moderator intervention required for these Nebula Graph questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426494/is-moderator-intervention-required-for-these-nebula-graph-questions)*

Answer (score 0):

Try the statement as below:

```
(
lookup on player yield id(vertex) as vid  
minus 
(lookup on player yield id(vertex) as vid | go 1 step from $-.vid over * bidirect yield distinct id($^) as vid)
)
| delete vertex $-.vid
```